# Using pygame to play a MIDI file from stream

Tags: python, io, pygame, midi, bytesio

What I want to do is the following: Create a MIDI file, but only in memory, and feed it into `pygame.mixer.music.load()`. Here is what I've been trying (I'm using MidiFile from [here](http://www.emergentmusics.org/midiutil)):

```
import pygame.mixer
import MidiFile3
import io

pygame.mixer.init()

midi = MidiFile3.MIDIFile(1) # midi file with one track
midi.addTrackName(0,0,"Track 1") #Track Name on track 0, position 0
midi.addTempo(0,0,120) #Tempo to 120 bpm on track 0, position 0

for i in range(8):
    midi.addNote(0,0,60,i,1,100) #add 8 c1-notes to the track

bytestream = io.BytesIO()
midi.writeFile(bytestream)
pygame.mixer.music.load(bytestream.getvalue())
```

Here I get the error message

```
pygame.error: File path 'MThd' contains null characters
```

When I do

```
bytestream = open('file.mid','wb')
midi.writeFile(bytestream)
bytestream.close()
pygame.mixer.music.load('file.mid')
```

it works as expected.

Of course, I know there is a difference between string containing a file name and a byte-string containing what the file contains. But I found this [Post on Daniweb](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216979/embed-and-play-midi-music-in-your-code-python#post1975147) which uses bytestreams and the example works for me.

I just can't figure out how to get my example to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue as follows:

```
bytestream = io.BytesIO()
midi.writeFile(bytestream)
temp = io.BytesIO(bytestream.getvalue())
pygame.mixer.music.load(temp)
```

As it seems, the `writeFile()` operation somehow makes the BytesIO object invalid to the `pygame.mixer.music.load()` method. By using the constructor of BytesIO again with the correctly created bytestream we magically get a valid bytestream we can pass to `pygame.mixer.music.load()`.

Comment: You are creating a new bytestream from the old bytestream, which is another, possibly expensive, step.   The stream pointer just has to be reset to the beginning with seek(0) as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `music.load()` function expectes a file name or a file object.

`bytestream.getvalue()` is the *contents* of the byte stream, which looks like a file name.

You have to use the file/`BytesIO` object itself:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(bytestream)
```

Comment: When I do that I get `pygame.error: Couldn't read from RWops`. Whatever that is supposed to mean.

Comment: I just found [this](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_RWops), but I was wondering why the example on daniweb.com [here](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216979/embed-and-play-midi-music-in-your-code-python#post1975147) works without using a file.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer, while it works, is not the proper solution.  All you need to do after writing the bytestream is reset the pointer to the beginning.  The proper code (section) follows:

```
bytestream = io.BytesIO()
midi.writeFile(bytestream)
bytestream.seek(0)
pygame.mixer.music.load(bytestream)
```

I had actually answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279864/generate-midi-file-and-play-it-without-saving-it-to-disk/27517644#27517644).